# How to compare 2 arrays and leave the one that has a similar value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays:

```
array1 = 
[{package_id: 4, is_checked: 1, images: Array(0)}]

array2 = 
[
{package_id: 3, width: "80", length: "120", height: "200", weight: "222", …},
{package_id: 4, width: "210", length: "70", height: "76", weight: "83", …}
]
```

The result I want to get is:

```
array3 = [{package_id: 4, width: "210", length: "70", height: "76", weight: "83", …}]
```

As you can see I removed the object where the package_id didn't match.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` in order to keep only the elements that have a matching `package_id` with at least one element of `array_1`.

```js
const array1 = [{
  package_id: 4,
  is_checked: 1,
  images: Array(0),
}];

const array2 = [{
    package_id: 3,
    width: '80',
    length: '120',
    height: '200',
    weight: '222',
  },
  {
    package_id: 4,
    width: '210',
    length: '70',
    height: '76',
    weight: '83',
  },
];

const filteredData = array2.filter(({
  package_id,
}) => array1.some(x => x.package_id === package_id));

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you filter `array2` by the `array1 package_id`

```js
array3 = array2.filter(e1 => array1.some(e2 => e1.package_id == e2.package_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could store your array1 ids at a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) first to avoid nested iteration while you filter, since `Set` [has method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) O(1) complexity. This would give better performance than calling filter and iterating over `array1` for each `array2` element:

```
  const ids = new Set()
  array1.forEach(({package_id}) => ids.add(package_id))
  const array3 = array2.filter(({package_id}) => ids.has(package_id))
```